# Update UI for a particular model value in Ember

Tags: ember.js

How to iterate over each model value and based on the value update the handlebar UI. 
I am using ArrayController. Basically for a particular value in the model I want to change how I display it.

I am not sure what is wrong in the above code. But it does not function as required.

```
App.SomeStat = Ember.Object.extend({
   target: null,
   starts: null
}

 {{#each stat in controller}}
     {{#if isRestricted}} Do something..
     {{/if}}
 {{/each}}

App.SomestatController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

isRestricted: function () {
        this.forEach(function(target) {
            var t= target.get('target');
            return t >= MAGIC_NUMBER;
        });
    }.property('model.@each.target'),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup the ArrayController `itemController` property to an ObjectController which extends the content for each array content.

```
App.ExtendIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  isRestricted: Em.computed(function () {
     return this.get('name') === 'red';
  }).property('name')


});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'extendIndex'
});
```

Then, you could access the added properties in your template when iterating the `controller`:

```
 {{#each controller}}

    <li>{{name}} ({{isRestricted}})</li>

 {{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gexos/1/edit

This case is documented in the [Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/) but I think, this specific case should documented as well.

Comment: Very nice, it was this easy but this difficult to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
App.CensusStat = Ember.Object.extend({
   targetPc: null,
   starts: null,
isRestricted: function () {

            var offTarget = this.get('targetPc');
            return (offTarget &&
                (Math.abs(offTarget) >=
                    Ember.I18n.t('ps.label.census.offtarget.restricted.percentage')));

    }.property('targetPc')
});
```

Comment: isRestricted should be in controller, I do not want to put that in the model. Thats like hack